# Visual Studio 2013 Intellisense Not Updating When Header File Changed in Other Project

Tags: visual-studio-2013, intellisense, solid-state-drive

I'm having a frustrating problem with C++ Intellisense in Visual Studio 2013. (If you're dealing with other versions of VS, please don't answer. Intellisense has changed dramatically over the versions, and my experience is that answers for one VS version aren't usually helpful for later versions.)

I frequently work in multiple projects with multiple instances of Visual Studio. When I make a change in a header file in a library, for example, Intellisense should detect the changed file and update the application project I also have open. This used to work, and I believe it stopped working when I installed an SSD. The behavior seems to indicate that VS simply doesn't detect when a file is changed on the disk outside of the current project.

I don't see how moving to an SSD would change that detection, but that's the best guess I have. I've experimented and searched for an answer without any luck, so any guidance would be helpful.

Thank you,
Doug

Comment: Further information, I was on VS 2013 Update 3 and just updated to Update 4, which did not solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The C++ IntelliSense never really tracked file modifications across Visual Studio instances. I believe your prior observations must have been an illusion or biased.

For example, one scenario where it might have "kind of" worked is: in instance A of Visual Studio you had `header.h` opened and applying modifications to, in instance B of Visual Studio you had `header.h` and `source.cpp`(using the header) opened. The opened `header.h` in instance B would be "noticing" the changes (there might be a dialog box asking for reloading the file, or the option to reload automatically might be set) and notifying the `source.cpp` IntelliSense to be reloaded. IntelliSense will also refresh the whole file periodically or in response to some user edits, so this might have been another explanation; although less deterministic, and of course should not be impacted by changing the hard drive.

In general, working on the same files across multiple Visual Studio instances is (as you can see) not well supported scenario. I would suggest an alternative approach to group your multiple projects into a single solution and work in a single instance. On a practical side, note that you might configure your own "workspace" solution which is referencing the select projects you need without impacting the team's solution files -- I do this quite frequently as I'm usually interested in only 2-3 projects out of N my team works on.

Comment: What you're saying does happen, of course, but I'm quite certain I'm not imagining this. It's extremely frustrating right now, and it wasn't like this. I'm pretty observant and I've been using VS for a long time. With the large number of libraries we use, it isn't practical to group them together into solutions. Thank you for the answer though...I appreciate the attempt to help.